# MapView- disable constantly caching maps

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

I am using quite a big offline map in my project. How I have made stress-test, where I opened and closed my map several times in a row, for each opening, app consumes about 2MB memory, in Log Cat I can often see OutOfMemoryError. Is there any way how to disable caching or how to clean cache?

Using: osmdroid 3.0.5

Comment: I've never used osmdroid, but I had a similar issue with mapforges and it was due to a memory leak. Have a look at Google I/O on MAT at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. It help me solving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
      final MapTileProviderBase mapTileProvider = this.mMapView.getTileProvider();
      mapTileProvider.clearTileCache();
}
```